# Test domain name for Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I am new in cloud platforms
I wanted to **test** openshift on AWS / GKE (I have working accounts on both the cloud) 
All tutorials pointing in pre-requisite that I need **a domain name**. sins domain names are not free and I just want to try this, how I can achive this without purchasing a domain name? Maybe with hosted zones, or Hostfile entry or Elastic load balancer. I am ok with temprory domain name

One idea in mind is to set up one machine with public IP and install free DNS app on it but I am not aware, how I can resolve domain names

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take it for a quick spin on those cloud environments, without the hassle of setup, consider a test drive instances.

- https://www.openshift.com/container-platform/trial.html

They are time limited, but okay for a quick play.

Comment: Hmmm, the AWS one seems to have been taken down for now. Only GCE and Azure at the moment.

Comment: I think it installs everything automatically "Deploy OpenShift Container Platform in minutes"  I would like to setup everything manually. Thing is I want to setup it on the bare metal platform, But before that, I want to try it in the cloud. I want to setup each master, node LBs manually. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Only to read through the documentation well. https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html